# Scrolling cells over UITableView with a fixed "Header"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uikit

I want the top of my `UITableView` to be a fixed view that the cells can scroll over like in the gif below. The text will change, and the button should be interactable.

How can I go about this? One idea I had was to add a subview behind the UITableView and offset the contentInset, but that would make the button unusable AFAIK.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Do the cells have to be Static Cells or can they be Dynamic Prototypes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution:

add the header view to container view, then add tableview as the header view's subview.

override tableview's method:

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(nullable UIEvent *)event;

If the header view have visible area(check tableview's contentOffset), and the point is inside the visible area, return false.